# Testing swagger parameters in vscode swagger3 preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, swagger-3.0

I have a swagger3 preview for an API that looks like this:

[image]

When I try to "Execute" this API it fails because it does not have a default `appId` to go with. How can I pass a default appId so that I can test this API through the swagger preview in vscode?